# cannot pass json in django context

Tags: javascript, python, django

I have some code like this.

```
def foobar():
    foo = [" 1", " 2", " 3"]
    context['json'] = json.dumps(foo)
    print context['json']
    return render_to_string('template', context)
```

I am getting what I think is correct printed to the terminal...

```
[" 1", " 2", " 3"]
```

but then in my javascript console I get the error `(index):59 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ;`

and when I go to where it is I see this...

```
[\u0022 1\u0022, \u0022 2\u0022, \u0022 3\u0022]
```

So I can see it's turning to unicode somewhere and then not being converted back but IDK what to do about it.

In my template (in `<script>` tags) I am doing this:

```
var data = {
    labels: {{ labels|escapejs }}
    datasets: []
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you are trying to pass an a json representation of an array to your javascript through the django template, escapejs shouldn't be used! It should just be

```
labels: {{ labels }}
```

note that in your view you are using the variable name `json` while in your template you are using `labels`. I assume this is a typo

If you are having trouble with quotes,

```
{% autoescape off %}{{ labels }}{% endautoescape %}
```

Comment: yes, typo...If I take away the escapejs I see "&quot; fish&quot"instead of the unicode code

Comment: Glad to have helped, i will edit my comment into the answer.